# Differing syntax? Microsoft Query vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel

Halo everyone.

I have built a code in MySQL and want to use it in an excel worksheets through Microsoft query.
A part of the code (second JOIN) have the purpose to reveal the date where the first transaction of a the customer took place. For that I have used the "row_number'' approach. The problem is that when I copy the code into my Microsoft query it looks like excel completely neglects the "row_number" function I have used. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
e.debtor_id, d.name, f.created as First_capture, cb.CARD, cb.BANKING
FROM
capital.cached_entry e

JOIN
capital.debtor d ON e.debtor_id = d.id

JOIN
(SELECT 
@row_number:=IF(@debtorid=t.debtor_id,@row_number+1,1) AS RowNumber, 
t.debtor_id,
t.created, 
te.fromState,
@debtorid:=t.debtor_id 
FROM capital.transaction t
JOIN capital.transaction_event te ON t.id=te.auth_entry_id
where toState='captured'
order by t.debtor_id, t.created) f ON f.debtor_id=e.debtor_id 

JOIN (SELECT 
debtor_id,
SUM(CASE when type='CARD_PAYMENT' then 1 else 0 end) as CARD,
SUM(CASE when type='BANKING_PAYMENT' then 1 else 0 end) as BANKING
FROM
capital.cached_entry e
JOIN
capital.debtor d ON e.debtor_id = d.id
WHERE
e.cacheType = 'DEBTOR'
GROUP by debtor_id) cb on e.debtor_id=cb.debtor_id


WHERE
e.cacheType = 'DEBTOR'
AND e.created <= '2016-10-25' and Rownumber=1
GROUP BY e.debtor_id
HAVING SUM(e.amount) != 0;
```

What am I doing wrong? Doesn't "row_number" exist in Microsoft query or is the function called something else?

Comment: row_number is not a function, it is a user defined variable in MySQL, so there is no naming issue here.

Comment: Query is just a thin wrapper around calling the database. It supports anything your database supports, as long as the query text is copied as-is and you ignore the designer completely.

Comment: You need to provide some further insights into the error itself, since the query is obviously OK from a syntax point of view if it runs in a MySQL environment.

Comment: Problemed solved. 
Turned out that I should change the ascending structure of the ordering to descending in Query. No clue why.. But htanks for the attention!